# Laravel projects under git-versioning with same base project

Tags: laravel, git

I'm developing with Laravel a suite of applications which are very different from each other, but must have the same base (graphics-functions-components-login-ecc.).
I just finished the base project, which I simply called 'template', and which is under git-versioning.
Now I have to develop the real applications, which will be extensions of 'template', but I want to keep pulling the base from 'template' and create some sort of 'git extension' for each application.
I would like to do this to keep the laravel tree structure of the project (so not use external folders) while avoiding to update each single application when I modify the 'template'.

I thought about link the same project folder to two different repositories (template+extension), using 'gitignore' to manage which file links to which repository, but I think it could be troublesome in case of new file added or so.
Maybe git has already an existing way to solve this, but I'm quite new and not expert to this, so I hope you'll guide me to the light.

Comment: I would create a package with all the functionality you need to reuse, but that still requires you to update every app whenever you update your package (base template). Unless you symlink it, but that might be a little fragile, especially on production.

Comment: @Loek you mean using composer packages?

Comment: For example, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git Submodules. Submodules are Git repositories nested inside a parent Git repository at a specific path in the parent repository’s working directory. For detail visit https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule.

Comment: You suggest to create a new project starting with 'template' as base and then add a submodule with the files of the app that extend 'template'? Is that correct?

Comment: No @AntonioMuzzolini , one module may be (ie many files) one feature, that can be reused in another application

Comment: base template, partials, controllers, models etc belongs to single feature can be a submodue

Comment: Ah in other words the opposite of what I understood! Ok, thanks

Comment: wlc @AntonioMuzzolini, if it helps you upvote answer :)